# How to connect draggable divs with jsPlumb?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I would like to connect two draggable divs using jsPlumb.  However when I use jsPlumb.Draggable function only the endpoints become draggable (not the div itself).  Here is the fiddle of what I what I am trying.

http://jsfiddle.net/rishabhsagar/PsytV/36/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seem to be working:

```
div.operation {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: something so simple...was this in the documentation? You would think that jsPlumb.draggable() would check style.

Comment: it does weirdly not: i use it with jquery UI and it seems to use its "draggable" event. it is unclear to me, why it does not auto-set "position" as UI does. I guess there is a reason!

Comment: I have the same problem! However my div position is absolute?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767889/jsplumb-draggable-not-working